# select events to receive push notification in ios

Tags: ios, push-notification

How to add events based push notifications in iOS. There are two such events for Messages app in the "Notification Center",

- Show Alerts from Evenyone.
- Show Alerts from My Contacts.

Similarly, for my app, I wanted to add the events through code when enabling push notification. The users can select one or more events for which notifications have to be pushed. I have check the documentation and registerForRemoteNotificationTypes doesn't help. Need to know if there is any other API to meet this requirement.

Comment: I think its no possible to configure from notification centre, event types for which push notification is not be enabled. This has to be held at the app settings itself. I have seen few apps like google+, hangout, foursquare,.. which does it from a separate screen like notifications setting.